# How to record the script for dynamic ID generation in Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I am working on Selenium IDE. Currently I am facing problem related to dynamic id.
I have recorded one script, but when I run it again it fails because id changes every time.

Is there any way to get rid of this??
Waiting for reply

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there recognizable way how those IDs change?

Comment: id's change on every iteration, and it is random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use other type of locators (for example xPath - as Pavel Janicek wrote).
Here is an article about Selenium locators http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=188
Read it and choose the best way for you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally - try switching from ID search to XPath. See examples here: http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example1.html

But in that case you have to know that your element is always first SPAN of second table (just example)

Comment: is it possible to use regular expression for same? if yes then how we can do that?

Comment: Personally, I haven't used regular expression in Selenium, but it is possible. Check this out http://pear.php.net/package/Testing_Selenium/docs/latest/Selenium/Testing_Selenium.html#methodselect

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found to get around this is to use the following xpath
//div[starts-with(@id,'match part of the id')][contains(text(), 'name of text')]