# Not able to locate an element, element id is not unique every time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate an element using xpath, but not able to make it unique as some part of element is come new every time. I have below element ID :

```
id= dnn_ctr173273_ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_AddNewLink
```

but for every portal the number get changes e.g. `173273` to `65662`

and id becomes `dnn_ctr65662_ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_AddNewLink`

Please suggest me how do i make it unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record the script for dynamic ID generation in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817869/how-to-record-the-script-for-dynamic-id-generation-in-selenium)

Comment: @SamHanley, The question you referencing doesn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the element by partial id

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("id*='ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_AddNewLink'"));
```

This will search for id witch contains the text `ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_AddNewLink`.

Answer (score 2):

Go through this,

```
css=a[id^='id_prefix_']

css=a[id$='_id_suffix']

css=a[id*='id_pattern']
```

Hope, it will definitely help you :)